# java.io.FileNotFoundException in Android Studio 4.1.2 when using getExternalStorageDirectory

Tags: android, file, emulation

I am trying to read a text file that is in my emulator but I can't find the file. getExternalStorageDirectory keeps returning this exception. To add the file, I simply dragged and dropped it in the emulator and it's showing up in the Files > Downloads folder. How do I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is targetting SDK below 29. Make sure your function is like: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`. This is to point to `Download` folder instead of point to root folder.

If your app is targeting SDK version 29 (Q), then there is privacy changes that restrict app to access public folder.
It is explained here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

So, the options are:

1. Change deprecated function of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `context.getExternalFilesDir()`, or `context.getExternalCacheDir()`, or `context.getExternalMediaDirs()`. Then instead putting the file in the download folder, you need to put the file to `../Android/data/com.yourpackagename/` (depends on device)
2. If you still want to use public folder and still want to use `getExternalStorageDirectory`, make sure to put `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest inside `<application>` tag
3. If you still want to use public folder, and want to get rid of deprecated `getExternalStorageDirectory`, you can use intent of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

If your app is already targetting SDK 30, it will be much easier, because we can now access the file path directly. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage
So, even though you are using `getExternalStorageDirectory`, the file should be accessible and should be no exception.

Also, make sure you have declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`